# What format does Git require for the commit email address?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I understand that Git requires an email address to be included with each commit. What requirements are there for the format of that address?

I am able, for example, to set a dot as the email address and commit that way. But some Git command produce an error (for example, rebasing done through TortoiseGit).

Here is the error:

[image]

When I configure a normal email address the error goes away.

I am interested in any general requirements for the email address. The error message appears to come from the standard Git library. So it might be the case that Git itself is performing certain validations.

Comment: "But some Git command produce an error"—please provide a concrete example. As far as I know, Git makes no constraints on email addresses. It _certainly_ doesn't constrain `.` in them.

Comment: I have added the error message for rebasing a commit onto its parent (a noop for testing purposes).

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with a `.` in your email address? That message doesn't say anything about that. I'm not sure what interface TortoiseGit gives you to set or view your `user.name` and `user.email`, but please check those values to ensue that both are configured. (On the command line you could run `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` to see, but this might be an issue with _Tortoise_, not Git itself.)

Comment: When I configure a normal email address the error goes away. I am able to commit using that "normal" address as well. The error message appears to come from the standard Git library. So it might be the case that Git itself is performing certain validations.

Comment: `libgit2` isn't "the standard Git library". It's a _common_ library, but Git from `git-scm.org` doesn't use it. And just because the error is coming from there doesn't mean it's that library's _fault_. If TortoiseGit fumbles valid email addresses and passes `null` or `""` or something into the library, that's on Tortoise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git requires a valid email address as specified in RFC 5322 and RFC 6532.   If you're using a single dot as the email address, that doesn't meet the production in those standards, and Git will reject it.

Now, Git does not verify strict conformance to those standards, but other Git implementations may do so and may choose to reject email addresses that are invalid, so you should choose an email address that is valid according to the RFCs.  It does do some basic sanity checking, however, which is what you're seeing.

Note that Git does permit internationalized email addresses, as well as quoted addresses with spaces.  Both of these are valid according to the RFCs.